# Jasmine Karma unit test json.parse function

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to unit test this line of javascript with Jasmine framework :

```
$scope.validerStyleTag = function() {
    $scope.currentTag = JSON.parse($scope.tagList);
    for (var i = $scope.listTags.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ($scope.listTags[i]._id === $scope.currentTag._id) {
            $scope.tagID = $scope.listTags[i]._id;
            $scope.listTags[i].disabled = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // var textestyler = angular.element(document.querySelector('#style-affected-add'))[0].outerHTML;
    // var debut = textestyler.substring(textestyler.indexOf('<p'), textestyler.indexOf('>') + 1);
    // var texteFinal = debut + '</p>';
    var mytext = '<p data-font="' + $scope.policeList + '" data-size="' + $scope.tailleList + '" data-lineheight="' + $scope.interligneList + '" data-weight="' + $scope.weightList + '" data-coloration="' + $scope.colorList + '"> </p>';


    $scope.tagStyles.push({
        id_tag: $scope.currentTag._id,
        style: mytext,
        label: $scope.currentTag.libelle,
        police: $scope.policeList,
        taille: $scope.tailleList,
        interligne: $scope.interligneList,
        styleValue: $scope.weightList,
        coloration: $scope.colorList,

    });
    angular.element($('.shown-text-add').text($('.shown-text-add').text()));
    angular.element($('#style-affected-add').removeAttr('style'));
    $scope.colorationCount = 0;
    $scope.tagList = null;
    $scope.policeList = null;
    $scope.tailleList = null;
    $scope.interligneList = null;
    $scope.weightList = null;
    $scope.colorList = null;

};
```

the problem of testing is in the first line :

```
$scope.currentTag = JSON.parse($scope.tagList);
```

when i begin to write my unit test like this and call my function  :

```
it('ProfilesCtrl:validerStyleTag should set validerStyleTag ', inject(function() {
expect($scope.validerStyleTag).toBeDefined();
$scope.validerStyleTag();


}));
```

karma is giving me an unexpected error : TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property at workFn (/home/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2107)

ideas or feedbacks are more than welcome !!

Comment: Are you using PhantomJS with an "old" version of Angular?  There was a bug that caused that error that has been fixed recently.  Looks like it was fixed in 1.2.12, if I read correctly. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5047

Comment: @CraigSquire THANK YOU for your answer, so how could i update my Angularjs version ? and phantomJs version ?

Comment: @CraigSquire i am using Angular v 1.2.1

Comment: I guess that all depends on how you reference Angular and installed PhantomJS in the first place.  You can just download the latest versions of each from their websites.  You can reference Angular from a cdn.  You can use NPM.

Comment: BTW, it was actually angular-mocks that had the bug.

Comment: @CraigSquire i did a bower update inside my bower.json

Comment: Let me know if the update fixes it or not.

Comment: @CraigSquire yes it does !!

Comment: Nice.  I ran into the same problem last week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using PhantomJS with an "old" version of Angular? There was a bug that caused that error that has been fixed recently. Looks like it was fixed in 1.2.12, if I read correctly.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5047